# How to get added token id, name list from the jquery-tokeninput plugin via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, token, jquery-tokeninput

How can I get the id, name value pairs of the tokens (entered by a user) via Javascript from the jquery-tokeninput plugin found here? https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput

Is it just me or isnt it surprising that this plugin has a lot of features except a straight forward getEnteredTokens() method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the demo page, you can get the ids using `$('#tokeninput-demo').val()`: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/.

Comment: Thanks but this would just give me a comma seperated id list wouldnt it? The ids would be of type string and not the original type which was passed via  a JSON array (since val() gets the value of the input type=text ). I need the id,name pairs entered as an array and in their original type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is kind of late coming, but have you tried:

```
selector.tokenInput("get");
```

for example:

```
var selectedValues = $('#myinputbox').tokenInput("get");
```

(where **selector** is whatever jQuery selector you need to return the tokeninput input object)
It returns all of the currently selected id/name values in an object.